# How to write data from console to .csv file with column headings

Tags: r

I am using R to perform some calculations to giving me R2 values, slope of a line, avg and Standard deviation. These data are displayed in the console but I need them to be written to a csv. file with column headings so that I can use this csv. file for further analysis.

Examples of my code are below:

```
`summary(lm(variable1~variable2, dataset))$r.squared`

 `Dataset %>%
  do({
  mod = lm(Variable1 ~ Variable2, data = .)
  data.frame(Slope = coef(mod)[2])`
```

I have tried to name these (ex. S1=(lm(variable1~variable2, dataset))$r.squared) and use this to write the data to a csv file using write.csv() and write.tbl but I have not been able to figure out how to get the data under the correct column heading below other values. I am somewhat new to R.

[image]

Does this help at all? The data in the console is what i am trying to write to a file.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is the object your wanting to save either a matrix or a data frame? `write.table` expects your object to be one of these, see `?write.table`. Note that `write.csv` is basically just a wrapper for CSVs using different parameter settings for `write.table`.

Comment: Write table did not work and this would explain why. The data that is returned are displayed either as a variable in the global env. (once I name it) and the other is returned as a table (again once I name it). I'm not necessarily fixed on using write.table or write.csv to get this job done, I am curious how others would solve this problem? I'm having trouble coming up with a solution.

Comment: Including some example data would be helpful to see exactly the kind of output you are looking for. It's not clear to me how you want to display R2 (a value associated with the whole model) alongside parameter information (slope, avg, stdev; for multiple variables). I assume `capture.output(summary(lm(...)), file = "out.txt")` isn't what you're looking for? So again, it would be helpful to see exactly the kind of output you want. I suspect the issue isn't in using `write.table`, but just organizing your data to use it properly. Also, have you looked at `writeLines`?

Comment: Actually, capture works! I can write information to the files and copy and paste them from there. Is there a way that you know of that I could have the information written into different columns rather than all one column but different rows?

Comment: That's going to depend on what your data look like. If it's a matrix, it's as simple as transposing with `t()`. Or `paste`ing some strings together may be helpful.

Comment: Ill get a picture of the data for you

Comment: It's not clear what you're wanting. `write.table` would work just fine putting that data into a file (it would be more helpful if you showed the data as it is in R with `dput()` instead of the image). Show us the R data you want exported and show *exactly* the kind of result you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Use the broom package replacing `stdout()` with your output file names.  Below we use the built-in data frame, `BOD`.

```
library(broom)

fm <- lm(demand ~ Time, BOD)

write.csv(glance(fm), stdout(), row.names = FALSE)
## "r.squared","adj.r.squared","sigma","statistic","p.value","df","logLik","AIC","BIC","deviance","df.residual"
## 0.644920230248548,0.556150287810685,3.08501562857815,7.2650743318886,0.0543539205107366,2,-14.0565762149087,34.1131524298174,33.4884308375016,38.0692857142857,4

write.csv(tidy(fm), stdout(), row.names = FALSE)
## "term","estimate","std.error","statistic","p.value"
## "(Intercept)",8.52142857142858,2.65894907888091,3.2048107423761,0.0327503317720233
## "Time",1.72142857142857,0.638658910594405,2.6953801831817,0.0543539205107367
```

Comment: Thank you! This would work in some circumstances but capture.output fits better for this situation because I have unique column headings.